Why is the JSessionID changing on initial requests in my Angular + Spring Boot application?
I'm working on an Angular application with a Spring Boot backend, where we use sessions for managing user state. Here is a brief overview of the setup:
The frontend is built with Angular, and I have set withCredentials: true so that cookies are sent with each request.
The backend is a Spring Boot application that manages sessions using JSESSIONID.
Issue: After the user logs in, the first few requests from Angular always receive a Set-Cookie header with a new JSESSIONID from the backend, causing the session ID to change multiple times. After a few requests, this behavior stops, and the session ID remains the same.
On the backend, it seems like multiple sessions are being created initially.
Questions:
Why does the JSESSIONID keep changing during the initial requests?
What could be causing multiple sessions to be created on the backend?
What I have checked so far:
Confirmed that withCredentials: true is correctly set in Angular.
Verified that the backend is properly configured to handle sessions.
Checked for any CORS misconfigurations that might be causing session issues.
Expected Behavior: The session ID should remain the same once the user is logged in.
Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this behavior would be greatly appreciated!


could it be changing right after login? Spring Security by default changes JSESSIONID upon authentication. This is on purpose to avoid session fixation attacks

yes it changes directly after login. but the old session is still present and is not beeing destroyed
